# How to Multiply an scalar with an XMM register

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, simd

I want to multiply a vector stored in `XMM0` register with an scalar how can I do it.

when I do VMULSS only multiply the firts value of the array.

Comment: You have to broadcast the scalar first with an instruction like `vbroadcastss`, like in https://github.com/vectorclass/version2/blob/fdd0258f77d51510aa44290f035c3021d568d478/vectorf128.h#L732 (check compiler output).  (Unless you have AVX-512 with the scalar in memory, then you can use a broadcast memory source operand.  Or first-gen Xeon Phi KNC which can do embedded-broadcast for register sources).

Comment: Which instruction set extensions are you permitted to use?

Comment: This is the kind of question where the easiest way to find the answer is generally to [ask a C/C++ compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/fdrGPTb3o).  That way you can also try different instruction sets to see what the best option for any target is.

Comment: [This Intel document on AVX512](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-512-intel-avx-512-instructions/overview-intrinsics-for-intel-advanced-vector-extensions-512-intel-avx-512-instructions.html) may be interesting regarding what @PeterCordes said (see Section "Embedded Broadcasting" at the end).

Comment: @JérômeRichard: That's a good resource, we should add it to some of the relevant tag wikis.  AVX-512 embedded broadcasts only work for memory source operands, unlike the KNCI precursor to AVX-512 which could do shuffles, similar to how ARM instructions have a barrel shifter for 2nd source.  (And that's a weird example, using a constant as the `set1` operand instead of talking about the power of AVX-512 to compile `add(v, set1(scalar_var))` into a single instruction.  Their `set1(1.0)` example only demonstrates the ability of a smart compiler to save space in .rodata storing the constant.)